# Probability events | Show that $P(A \cap B) = 0.257379$

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Considering 2 events $A$ and $B$ in sample space $S$. Suppose

\begin{align}
P(A \cup B) = 0.7949 \\
P(B^c |A) = 0.5835 \\ 
P(A^c |B) = 0.4074 \\ 
P(A^c \cap B^c) = 0.2051.
\end{align}

Show that $P(AB) = 0.257379$ (correct solution).

***My wrong attempt***

$1-P(A^c \cap B^c)- P(B^c |A) = 0.3784$

Please could you show how the answer $\left( P(A \cap B) = 0.257379\right)$ was found using the given probabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small hint: the last equality follows from the first, so you can ignore it.

Calculate
$$P(B\mid A) = 1 - P(B^c\mid A) = 1- 0.5835= 0.4165\\
P(A \mid B) = 1 - P(A^c\mid B) = 1 - 0.4074=0.5926$$

Now, using the basic formula for the conditional probability we get
$$\frac{P(AB)}{P(A)} = 0.4165\\
\frac{P(AB)}{P(B)} =0.5926$$
and so
$$P(A) = \frac{1}{0.4165} P(AB)\\
P(B) = \frac{1}{0.5926}P(AB)$$

Now use also the fact
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A) +P(B) - P(AB)$$
given to be $0.7949$.  From the last three equalities you should be able to get $P(AB)$.

Answer (score 2):

We have:

$$P(B|A) = 1- P(B^c|A) = 0.4165 = \frac {P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$$

$$P(A|B) = 1- P(A^c|B) = 0.5926 = \frac {P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B) = 0.7949$$

Can you use the equations above to solve for $P(A \cap B)$? Try to express $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ in terms of $P(A \cap B)$ and substitute them into the last equation.

Comment: I got this from a student I was tutoring and seems to be from a good source. I can't seem to find the same solution though. I see what you mean. I have tried Bayes and De Morgan.

Comment: From this method I got the answer $0.257379189...$